# Network w/ name (onlyoffice) already exists but unable to locate package when I go to uninstall

Tags: networking, package-management

I want to setup OnlyOffice but Ubuntu claims it already exists. 
I could not find it so went to uninstall it and it can't locate it.

Here it is:::

```
$ sudo docker network create --driver bridge onlyoffice
Error response from daemon: **network with name onlyoffice already exists**

$ sudo apt-get remove onlyoffice
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: **Unable to locate package onlyoffice**

$ sudo apt-get purge onlyoffice
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: **Unable to locate package onlyoffice**
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a `docker` network.
You should remove it by `docker network rm onlyoffice`, not by `apt-get`